# PHP Magento API catalog_product.info not working when running through a list

Tags: api, magento

I am trying to create a magento API to get the pricing of each item. I have a table with all the SKU's i need to get info for. i ran the following for one item and it worked

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.mysite.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('user', 'pass');
$productId = 'ABC';
$att = array("visibility","sku","special_price", "price");
$arguments = array( $productId, NULL, $att);
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $arguments);
echo $result['visibility'].",".$result['sku'].",".$result['special_price'].",".$result['price'];
```

the above code worked fine.

then i tested another code to make sure that my code to query the database and loop through each sku works

```
$getskus = "SELECT sku FROM items;";
$skus = mysqli_query($con, $getskus);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($skus))
{
    $productId = $row['sku'];
    echo $productId."<br>";
}
```

The above code works fine. My issue is when i combine the 2 i get a blank screen.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.mysite.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('user', 'pass');

$getskus = "SELECT sku FROM items;";
$skus = mysqli_query($con, $getskus);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($skus))
{
    $productId = $row['sku'];
    $att = array("visibility","sku","special_price", "price");
    $arguments = array( $productId, NULL, $att);
    $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $arguments);
    echo $result['visibility'].",".$result['sku'].",".$result['special_price'].",".$result['price'];

}
```

i get nothing. Any ideas?

update: if $row['sku'] = '9005' will magento think its a product id instead of a SKU?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $arguments);
```

This can't accept $arguments as the third param. Instead:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $row['sku'], null, $att, 'sku');
```

NB: not sure if 'null' (4th param) is a valid argument for store view. To be safe, replace with the correct store view (`default`, in most cases).

RTM: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

Comment: but when i use $arguments as in the first set of code above it does work

Comment: i think it might have to do with the fact that some of my SKU's are actually just numbers

Comment: that is why you have to specify that last arg as 'sku' on my suggestion.